# Implicit interface, class casting in JAVA

Tags: java, interface, casting

I am learning for a JAVA Programmer I certificate and among questions there is one I can't understand:

```
//Given:

interface I{}
class A implements I{}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B{}

//and

A a = new A();
B b = new B();
```

Identify options that will compile and run without error.

```
A. a = (B)(I)b;
B. b = (B)(I)a;
C. a = (I)b;
D. I i = (C)a;
```

Now I know that the answer is A) but I don't get it, if the class B is a child of class A, then 'a' can be equal to 'b' without casting, why is the answer B) wrong? What does even casting (B)(I) means?

Comment: look to it like this all B are A but not all A are B. In this example only B extends A but there might be a new class Z extends A which will be an A but will not be a B

Answer (score 2):

B extends A.  So you can cast instances of B to A but not the other way around. The code will compile, but will throw a ClassCastException at runtime.

Trying to cast to a descendant class is called downcasting. The cast to 'I' in this case is what would allow that code to compile, but result in the ClassCastException being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

1. Parent reference can be used to hold child objects. Thus below all are correct.

   ```
   A a = new A();
   B b = new B();
   I i = new A();
   a = new B();
   b = new C();
   ```
2. Below has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.Thus below will throw the CCE.

   ```
   b = (B)(I)a;
   c = (C)(I)a;
   ```

   You may check the same as `System.out.println(a instanceof C);`